# How to use Go with LDAP protocol

Tags: ldap, go

How can I use Go to call and manage **Ldap** protocol directly? are there any packages? or must I use udp and tcp?

Comment: Did you search? https://github.com/tonnerre/go-ldap is top result in Google

Comment: I recommend [godoc.org](http://godoc.org) for searching for libararies. [http://godoc.org/?q=ldap](http://godoc.org/?q=ldap)

Comment: For some minimalistic server support I made this: https://github.com/bradleypeabody/godap

Comment: @CharlesB actually this thread _is_ the top result (https://www.google.com/search?q=golang%20ldap)

Answer (score 18):

There is no LDAP library in the Go standard libraries, but a quick Google search reveals several you could try:

- https://github.com/mmitton/ldap
- https://github.com/tonnerre/go-ldap

This second one is actually a fork of the first one. On github you can always view the open issues, last update and forking network (https://github.com/mmitton/ldap/network) to get a pretty good sense of which library you should use when there is a lot of forking.

If you need a library for something omitted in the Go standard libraries there are several good places to look:

- Always start with a quick Google search
- Checkout: http://go-lang.cat-v.org/pure-go-libs / http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings
- And: http://godoc.org/
- And: http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Projects

If all of those fail you and you don't feel up to creating your own implementation, keep in mind you can always use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to call C code (such as one of the many C LDAP libraries for example) from Go.

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap, the above projects expired and no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 11):

Thought I should add my ten cents here. It is an old post, but here it is nonetheless

I used the [https://github.com/mavricknz/ldap](http://github.com/mavricknz/ldap) library after using the `mmitton/ldap` one as mentioned by voidlogic above. The problem with the mmitton lib is that it does not handle escape characters very well in the filter.

```
The test filter: (&(objectClass=user)(cn=wickd(bracketTest )))

Escaped Filter:  (&(objectClass=user)(cn=wickd\28bracketTest \29))
```

The `MMitton library` just came back with a filter compile error even with the escaped filter. Loaded the Mavricknz lib and it worked. Even comes with EscapeFilter function! brilliance!

Anyhow... Thought I should post this for anyone that had the same struggle as I did :)

Answer (score 3):

I started to write a helper library for building server software capable of speaking the LDAP protocol.
There are some usage samples included.

- https://github.com/vjeantet/ldapserver

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, for the server end of it, I wrote this package (in Go) a while ago:
https://github.com/bradleypeabody/godap

It's not a full LDAP server but works well for implementing authentication on top of another data source (something I have been unable to find any other project that addresses).

It does a lot of "manage Ldap protocol directly" :)

Comment: Looks cool! Will have a look was looking for something like this

Answer (score 2):

For a simple high-level ldap client, see [go-ldap-client](https://github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client), [go docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/jtblin/go-ldap-client).

Most of the options on https://godoc.org/?q=ldap
are just forks of another one, most of them are too low level or too limited (e.g. do not return errors 
which make it hard to troubleshoot issues).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide LDAP based authentication on your web page, you may like the solution I created: `go-ldapc` is a LDAP Authentication Client Module, with only one API.

It's on [github - sona-tar/go-ldapc](https://github.com/sona-tar/go-ldapc).